# org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, web-applications

I m trying to book a table. But when I pressing the book table button I get an error. Error is Request method 'POST' is not supported. I've done it before in other similar projects, it worked. I think the problem is in the HTML file but I couldn't find it. How can I fix That?
Here is my Entity Class

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "reservation")
public class Reservation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "arrival_date")
    private String arrivalDate;

    @Column(name = "arrival_time")
    private String arrivalTime;

    @Column(name = "num_of_person")
    private String numOfPerson;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "phone_number")
    private String phoneNumber;
```

Here is my Controller Class

```java
@Controller
public class RestaurantController {

    @Autowired
    private ReservationService reservationService;
    
    @InitBinder
    public void init(WebDataBinder binder) {
        StringTrimmerEditor editor = new StringTrimmerEditor(true);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(StringTrimmerEditor.class, editor);
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "index";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/reservation")
    public String reservation(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("newRes", new Reservation());
        return "reservation";
        
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/save-reservation")
    public String proceed(@Valid @ModelAttribute("newRes") Reservation reservation, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        reservationService.saveReservation(reservation);
        return "redirect:/reservation";
        
    }
}
```

And here is my HTML File

```html
<form id="contactForm" th:action="@{/save-reservation}" th:object="${newRes}" method="post" >
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Book a table</h3>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="input_date" class="datepicker picker__input form-control" th:field="*{arrivalDate}" type="text" value="" equired data-error="Please enter Date">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="input_time" class="time form-control picker__input" th:field="*{arrivalTime}" required data-error="Please enter time">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="custom-select d-block form-control" id="person" th:field="*{numOfPerson}" required data-error="Please select Person">
                        <option  value="0">Select Person*</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Contact Details</h3>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" th:field="*{firstName}" placeholder="Your Name" required data-error="Boş Bırakılamaz">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Email" id="email" class="form-control" th:field="*{email}" required data-error="Boş Bırakılamaz">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Numbar" id="phone" class="form-control" th:field="*{phoneNumber}" required data-error="Boş Bırakılamaz">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="submit-button text-center">
                <button class="btn btn-common" id="submit" type="submit">Book Table</button>
```

Comment: Please add the error/stacktrace to your question.

Comment: Error is Request method 'POST' is not supported.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Please add the full error and/ stacktrace to your question. That is just a snippet (the first line or so).

Comment: u mean like this? When i pressing Book Table button .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation is correct. try reloading maven or clean your cache

Comment: still not working. I do not understand. I've done a few more projects like this and they all worked. I don't understand why this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

add this dependency in your pom.xml... I ran your code in my system. It running fine most probably the page which you are getting is from cached use this dependency it does not allow to store any value in the cache.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Comment: still doesnt work. I used the same methods in another project and it worked. I don't understand why this is not working

Comment: ok lets verify cacheing thing change that reservetaion.html name to some res and try..i copied same code what you have provided and i am getting the proper outpt

Comment: One thing i forgot to tell you i removed @Valid from post mapping. that is the only change i did in your code.

Comment: no man still same. looks like i can not fix that.

Comment: Can you share error-stack trace from your terminal/console of ide